# Python regexp: Get the substring which does not match the particular pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a multi line string as follows,

```
x1:x1:name: n1
x1:name: n5
x1:x2:name: n2
x2:name: n4
x2:x1:name: n3
```

I want to match only the strings with pattern -
`x[0-9]:name: n[0-9]`

and not the pattern - `x[0-9]:x[0-9]:name: n[0-9]`

I tried the following regexp, which matches all the lines.

```
my_pattern = "[ \t]*([0-9xa-f]+):name:[ \t]+([0-9A-Za-z_%-]+)"
my_pattern = re.compile(my_pattern)
reqnames = my_pattern.findall(output)
```

Comment: You could add anchors `^x[0-9]:name: n[0-9]$`

Comment: So, use `(?m)^x[0-9]:name: n[0-9]$`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27572562/3832970)